# Python system variable path not working on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, windows-10

I'm unable to setup a Python programming environment on my PC. I am trying to setup system variables, but it does not work. My PATH is:

```
C:\Python36;c:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python36\Scripts\
```

I'm expecting that output without red marked portion:

[image: Windows PowerShell output:]

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"? You show a path and a screenshot of Python and setuptools version information, but no indication of an issue.

Comment: There's generally no reason for the "site-packages" directory to be in `PATH`. Also, it should never be added to `PYTHONPATH`. The interpreter adds it automatically to `sys.path`.